# MySQL Join SUM column on the whole table

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join

Let's say I had the following table:

```
id    num_votes    total_rating
-------------------------------
1     20           30
2     40           13
3     15           25
```

I want to join the SUM of all `id`s, let's say, onto the entire table so it looks like:

```
id    num_votes    total_rating    sum
--------------------------------------
1     20           30              6
2     40           13              6
3     15           25              6
```

I tried to do a LEFT JOIN on itself but I only get a 1 row result -- any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  t.*, idsum
FROM    (
        SELECT  SUM(id) AS idsum
        FROM    mytable
        ) q,
        mytable t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, num_votes, total_rating, (SELECT SUM(id) FROM `table`) AS sum FROM `table`
```

This is an inline select and they can be expensive. But it works here.

Comment: It's an uncorrelated scalar subquery so in theory it should only be executed once and not repeated for every row

Comment: I looked at the EXPLAIN results of a test query and this subquery ran only once. So this has two queries running through all rows.